# How to print list of connected devices

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, libusb

Please have a look at the following code, which is coded to get the list of USB devices connected

```
#include <lusb0_usb.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();

    struct usb_bus *busses = usb_get_busses();
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;


    for(bus=busses;bus;bus=bus->next)
    {
        for(dev=bus->devices;dev;dev->next)
        {
            cout << dev->descriptor.iProduct << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get

```
Starting C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\USB-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_beta2_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Release\release\USB.exe...
C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\USB-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_beta2_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Release\release\USB.exe exited with code 0
```

I believe I have done this code incorrectly. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably running fine.  You need to pause the console so you can see the output.

Try adding

```
#include <conio.h> 

_getch();
```

Or use some other technique to pause and wait for user input.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in objective-C:

```
libusb_device **devs; //pointer to pointer of device, used to retrieve a list of devices
ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list
//libusb_set_debug(ctx, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation
cnt = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs); //get the list of devices
if(cnt < 0) {
    return false;
    //there was an error
}
//print total number of usb devices
ssize_t i; //for iterating through the list
for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    if (libusb_get_device_descriptor(devs[i], &desc) >= 0) {
        if ((desc.idVendor == 0x04D8) && (desc.idProduct == 0x0204)){
            libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, unref the devices in it

return false;
```

I believe you need to go "descriptor.i **d** Product" instead.